# How to assign QButtonGroup to a layout

Tags: qt, pyqt

How do we assign a QButtonGroup to a layout?

```
radioLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout() 
radioGroup=QtGui.QButtonGroup()
radioLayout.addWidget(radioGroup)
```

Getting `TypeError` error on the last line trying to add radioGroup to the layout.
What would be a correct way?

Comment: A `QButtonGroup` is not a visual item (a.k.a. widget) that can be placed in a layout.  It is merely a container for managing the states of the buttons in the group.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [grouping radio buttons in PyQt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14798058/grouping-radio-buttons-in-pyqt)

Answer (score 0):

`QButtonGroup` is not a `Qwidget`, it's a comfortable implementation of `List<QPushButton>`, of course, you can add all buttons into `QLayout` but it's more difficult than simple `addWidget` method, so code:

```
QList<QAbstractButton*> buttonList=m_buttonGroup->buttons();
    for (QList<QAbstractButton*>::const_iterator it=buttonList.cbegin(); it!=buttonList.cend(); ++it)
    {
        layout->addWidget(*it);
    }
```