# QRadioButtons widget are linked on uniqueness

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qradiobutton

I have built a GUI window that is part of a project, and I need to have three separate groups of radio-buttons, each group must be independent in the uniqueness. I can't find the way how to separate the linkage between the radio-buttons. So only one can be checked, and all the others are automatically unchecked.

I tried to use QtWidgets.QButtonGroup But the code failed and I don't understand why.

How can create separate groups that are independent?

this is the code I have:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QListWidget, QGridLayout, QListWidgetItem, QPushButton, QMessageBox, QLineEdit
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class Add_Element(QDialog):
    #    def __init__(self, item_ls, parent=None):
    #        super(Calc_pro, self).__init__(parent)
    def __init__(self, item_ls, parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(Add_Element, item_ls)
    def setupUi(self, Add_Element, item_ls):
        self.result = ""
        self.floor_data = []  # This is a list of a set of all the parameters needed for a single simulation
        self.floor_data = ["no_floor", 0.0, "no file", 1.0, "0.0", "0.0", "20.", "20.", "50", 0, "no description"]
        self.simulations_data_list = []  # This list will save all self.floor_data that the user defined, and will be

        self.hbox1 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.hbox2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.hbox3 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.hbox4 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.gbox1 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.gbox2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.hbox5 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.hbox6 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.hbox7 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()

        # =================================================
        # Header - hbox 1
        # =================================================
        self.calc_pop_lbl = QtWidgets.QLabel("Electrical Element", self)
        self.hbox1.addWidget(self.calc_pop_lbl)
        font_big = QtGui.QFont()
        font_big.setPointSize(14)
        font_big.setBold(True)
        font_big.setWeight(75)
        self.calc_pop_lbl.setFont(font_big)
        self.calc_pop_lbl.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

        font_bld = QtGui.QFont()
        font_bld.setPointSize(12)
        font_bld.setBold(True)
        font_bld.setWeight(75)

        # ==============================
        # Name & Type - hbox 2
        # ==============================
        self.element_name_lbl = QtWidgets.QLabel("Element Type", self)
        self.hbox2.addWidget(self.element_name_lbl)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.element_name_lbl.setFont(font)
        self.element_name_lbl.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.element_selection_comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self)
        self.hbox2.addWidget(self.element_selection_comboBox)
        self.element_selection_comboBox.setFont(font)
        self.element_selection_comboBox.setToolTip("<html><head/><body><p>Select the Type</p></body></html>")
        self.element_selection_comboBox.addItem("לוח רגיל")  # 0
        self.element_selection_comboBox.addItem("לוח קומפקטי")  # 1
        self.element_selection_comboBox.addItem("Cable Square")  # 2
        self.element_selection_comboBox.addItem("Cable Flat")  # 3
        self.element_selection_comboBox.addItem("Trafo Long")  # 4
        self.element_selection_comboBox.addItem("Trafo Broad")  # 5
        self.element_selection_comboBox.addItem("כבל דו-גידי")  # 6
        self.element_selection_comboBox.addItem("חוט בודד")  # 7
        self.element_selection_comboBox.addItem("Cable 3Phase ELMF")  # 8
        self.element_selection_comboBox.addItem("Cable 1Phase ELMF")  # 9

        self.element_name_lbl = QtWidgets.QLabel("Element Name", self)
        self.hbox2.addWidget(self.element_name_lbl)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.element_name_lbl.setFont(font)
        self.element_name_lbl.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.element_name_input = QtWidgets.QLineEdit("Panel")
        self.element_name_input.setFont(font)
        self.hbox2.addWidget(self.element_name_input)
        # ==============================
        # Description - hbox 3
        # ==============================
        self.element_desc_lbl = QtWidgets.QLabel("Element Description", self)
        self.element_desc_lbl.setFont(font)
        self.element_name_lbl.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.element_desc_input = QtWidgets.QLineEdit("לוח ראשי קק")
        self.element_desc_input.setFont(font)
        self.hbox3.addWidget(self.element_desc_lbl)
        self.hbox3.addWidget(self.element_desc_input)

        # =====================================
        # Position - grid box 1
        # ======================================
        self.start_lbl = QtWidgets.QLabel("Start Point")
        self.end_lbl = QtWidgets.QLabel("End Point")
        self.start_lbl.setFont(font)
        self.end_lbl.setFont(font)
        self.gbox1.addWidget(self.start_lbl, 1, 2, 1, 1)
        self.gbox1.addWidget(self.end_lbl, 1, 3, 1, 1)

        self.x_lbl = QtWidgets.QLabel("X[m]")
        self.x_lbl.setFont(font)
        self.gbox1.addWidget(self.x_lbl, 2, 1, 1, 1)

        self.y_lbl = QtWidgets.QLabel("Y[m]")
        self.y_lbl.setFont(font)
        self.gbox1.addWidget(self.y_lbl, 3, 1, 1, 1)

        self.z_lbl = QtWidgets.QLabel("Z[m]")
        self.z_lbl.setFont(font)
        self.gbox1.addWidget(self.z_lbl, 4, 1, 1, 1)

        self.xs_pos = QtWidgets.QLineEdit("0")
        self.xs_pos.setFont(font)
        self.gbox1.addWidget(self.xs_pos, 2, 2, 1, 1)

        self.ys_pos = QtWidgets.QLineEdit("0")
        self.ys_pos.setFont(font)
        self.gbox1.addWidget(self.ys_pos, 3, 2, 1, 1)

        self.zs_pos = QtWidgets.QLineEdit("0")
        self.zs_pos.setFont(font)
        self.gbox1.addWidget(self.zs_pos, 4, 2, 1, 1)

        self.xe_pos = QtWidgets.QLineEdit("0")
        self.xe_pos.setFont(font)
        self.gbox1.addWidget(self.xe_pos, 2, 3, 1, 1)

        self.ye_pos = QtWidgets.QLineEdit("0")
        self.ye_pos.setFont(font)
        self.gbox1.addWidget(self.ye_pos, 3, 3, 1, 1)

        self.ze_pos = QtWidgets.QLineEdit("0")
        self.ze_pos.setFont(font)
        self.gbox1.addWidget(self.ze_pos, 4, 3, 1, 1)

        self.length_lbl = QtWidgets.QLabel("Length[m]")
        self.length_lbl.setFont(font)
        self.gbox1.addWidget(self.length_lbl, 5, 1, 1, 1)

        self.length = QtWidgets.QLineEdit("1.0")
        # self.length.setReadOnly(True)
        self.length.setFont(font)
        self.gbox1.addWidget(self.length, 5, 2, 1, 1)

        self.dir_lbl = QtWidgets.QLabel("Direction")
        self.dir_lbl.setFont(font)
        self.dir_lbl.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)
        self.gbox1.addWidget(self.dir_lbl, 5, 3, 1, 1)

        # direction_group = QtWidgets.QButtonGroup()
        self.dir_x = QtWidgets.QRadioButton("X")
        self.dir_x.setChecked(True)
        self.dir_y = QtWidgets.QRadioButton("Y")
        self.dir_z = QtWidgets.QRadioButton("Z")

        self.gbox1.addWidget(self.dir_x, 5, 4, 1, 1)
        self.gbox1.addWidget(self.dir_y, 5, 5, 1, 1)
        self.gbox1.addWidget(self.dir_z, 5, 6, 1, 1)
        # direction_group.addButton(self.dir_x, 0)
        # direction_group.addButton(self.dir_y, 1)
        # direction_group.addButton(self.dir_z, 2)

        self.load_defaults_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Load Defaults")

        self.load_defaults_btn.setFont(font)

        # ------------------------------------------
        # gbox2
        # ------------------------------------------

        self.currant_lbl = QtWidgets.QLabel("Currents and Power")
        self.currant_lbl.setFont(font_bld)
        self.frame_current = QtWidgets.QFrame()
        self.frame_current.setObjectName("frame_current")
        self.imax_radio = QtWidgets.QRadioButton("Imax[A]")
        self.imax_radio.setFont(font)
        self.ityp_radio = QtWidgets.QRadioButton("Ityp[A]")
        self.ityp_radio.setFont(font)
        self.ityp_radio.setChecked(True)
        self.imax_input = QtWidgets.QLineEdit("100")
        self.ityp_input = QtWidgets.QLineEdit("60")
        self.imax_input.setFont(font)
        self.ityp_input.setFont(font)
        i_group = QtWidgets.QButtonGroup()
        self.gbox2.addWidget(self.currant_lbl, 1, 1, 1, 3)
        self.gbox2.addWidget(self.imax_radio, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        self.gbox2.addWidget(self.ityp_radio, 3, 1, 1, 1)
        self.gbox2.addWidget(self.imax_input, 2, 2, 1, 1)
        self.gbox2.addWidget(self.ityp_input, 3, 2, 1, 1)
        i_group.addButton(self.imax_radio, 0)
        i_group.addButton(self.ityp_radio, 1)

        self.typ_max_ratio_lbl = QtWidgets.QLabel("Typ/Max Ratio")
        self.typ_max_ratio_lbl.setFont(font)
        self.imbalance_lbl = QtWidgets.QLabel("Imbalance factor")
        self.imbalance_lbl.setFont(font)
        self.typ_max_input = QtWidgets.QLineEdit("0.6")
        self.imbalance_input = QtWidgets.QLineEdit("0.3")
        self.typ_max_input.setFont(font)
        self.imbalance_input.setFont(font)
        self.gbox2.addWidget(self.typ_max_ratio_lbl, 4, 1, 1, 1)
        self.gbox2.addWidget(self.imbalance_lbl, 5, 1, 1, 1)
        self.gbox2.addWidget(self.typ_max_input, 4, 2, 1, 1)
        self.gbox2.addWidget(self.imbalance_input, 5, 2, 1, 1)

        self.voltage_lbl = QtWidgets.QLabel("Voltage[V]")
        self.voltage_lbl.setFont(font)
        self.power_lbl = QtWidgets.QLabel("Power[kVA]")
        self.power_lbl.setFont(font)
        self.voltage_input = QtWidgets.QLineEdit("220")
        self.power_input = QtWidgets.QLineEdit("1000")
        self.voltage_input.setFont(font)
        self.power_input.setFont(font)
        self.power_input.setReadOnly(True)
        self.voltage_input.setReadOnly(True)
        self.gbox2.addWidget(self.voltage_lbl, 3, 4, 1, 1)
        self.gbox2.addWidget(self.power_lbl, 4, 4, 1, 1)
        self.gbox2.addWidget(self.voltage_input, 3, 5, 1, 1)
        self.gbox2.addWidget(self.power_input, 4, 5, 1, 1)

        self.parameters_lbl = QtWidgets.QLabel("Physical Dimensions")
        self.parameters_lbl.setFont(font_bld)
        self.h_lbl = QtWidgets.QLabel("H[m]")
        self.h_lbl.setFont(font)
        self.d_lbl = QtWidgets.QLabel("d[m]")
        self.d_lbl.setFont(font)
        self.hc_lbl = QtWidgets.QLabel("Hc[m]")
        self.hc_lbl.setFont(font)
        self.dt_lbl = QtWidgets.QLabel("dT[m]")
        self.dt_lbl.setFont(font)

        trafo_group = QtWidgets.QButtonGroup()
        self.dry_radio = QtWidgets.QRadioButton("Dry")
        self.dry_radio.setFont(font)
        self.oil_radio = QtWidgets.QRadioButton("Oil")
        self.oil_radio.setFont(font)
        self.dry_radio.setChecked(True)
        self.h_input = QtWidgets.QLineEdit("1.8")
        self.d_input = QtWidgets.QLineEdit("0.15")
        self.hc_input = QtWidgets.QLineEdit("0")
        self.dt_input = QtWidgets.QLineEdit("0")
        self.h_input.setFont(font)
        self.d_input.setFont(font)
        self.hc_input.setFont(font)
        self.dt_input.setFont(font)

        self.gbox2.addWidget(self.parameters_lbl, 1, 6, 1, 2)
        self.gbox2.addWidget(self.h_lbl, 2, 6, 1, 1)
        self.gbox2.addWidget(self.d_lbl, 3, 6, 1, 1)
        self.gbox2.addWidget(self.hc_lbl, 4, 6, 1, 1)
        self.gbox2.addWidget(self.dt_lbl, 5, 6, 1, 1)
        self.gbox2.addWidget(self.h_input, 2, 7, 1, 1)
        self.gbox2.addWidget(self.d_input, 3, 7, 1, 1)
        self.gbox2.addWidget(self.hc_input, 4, 7, 1, 1)
        self.gbox2.addWidget(self.dt_input, 5, 7, 1, 1)
        self.gbox2.addWidget(self.oil_radio, 6, 6, 1, 1)
        self.gbox2.addWidget(self.dry_radio, 6, 7, 1, 1)
        trafo_group.addButton(self.oil_radio, 0)
        trafo_group.addButton(self.dry_radio, 1)

        self.sheild_lbl = QtWidgets.QLabel("Sheilding & Twisting")
        self.sheild_lbl.setFont(font_bld)
        self.twist_reduction_lbl = QtWidgets.QLabel("Twist Reduction")
        self.shield_chk = QtWidgets.QCheckBox("Shield Reduction")
        self.twist_chk = QtWidgets.QCheckBox("Cable Twist")
        self.mu_relative_lbl = QtWidgets.QLabel("µr Relative Permeability")
        self.thickness_lbl = QtWidgets.QLabel("Thickness[m]")
        self.distance_lbl = QtWidgets.QLabel("Distamce[m]")
        self.twist_reduction_input = QtWidgets.QLineEdit("1")
        self.mu_relative_input = QtWidgets.QLineEdit("100")
        self.thickness_input = QtWidgets.QLineEdit("0.001")
        self.distance_input = QtWidgets.QLineEdit("0.05")
        self.gbox1.addWidget(self.sheild_lbl, 1, 7, 1, 2)
        self.gbox1.addWidget(self.twist_reduction_lbl, 2, 7, 1, 1)
        self.gbox1.addWidget(self.shield_chk, 3, 7, 1, 1)
        self.gbox1.addWidget(self.twist_chk, 3, 8, 1, 1)
        self.gbox1.addWidget(self.mu_relative_lbl, 4, 7, 1, 1)
        self.gbox1.addWidget(self.thickness_lbl, 5, 7, 1, 1)
        self.gbox1.addWidget(self.distance_lbl, 6, 7, 1, 1)
        self.gbox1.addWidget(self.twist_reduction_input, 2, 8, 1, 1)
        self.gbox1.addWidget(self.mu_relative_input, 4, 8, 1, 1)
        self.gbox1.addWidget(self.thickness_input, 5, 8, 1, 1)
        self.gbox1.addWidget(self.distance_input, 6, 8, 1, 1)
        self.gbox1.setSpacing(10)
        self.gbox2.setSpacing(10)

        self.save_definition_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Save Definition")
        self.save_definition_btn.setFont(font)

        spacerItem1 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)

        self.hbox4.addItem(spacerItem1)
        self.hbox4.addWidget(self.load_defaults_btn)
        self.hbox4.addItem(spacerItem1)
        self.hbox4.addWidget(self.save_definition_btn)
        self.hbox4.addItem(spacerItem1)

        # =================================================
        # Hbox6 Description
        # =================================================
        self.dev_img = QtGui.QPixmap("C:\mfc\modelPic\Panel.jpg")
        self.img = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.img.setPixmap(self.dev_img)
        self.img.setScaledContents(False)
        self.hbox6.addWidget(self.img)

        # =================================================
        # listbox
        # =================================================
        # row = 0
        # self.hbox6.addWidget(self.listWidget)
        # self.hbox1.addWidget(self.listWidget, row, 0, 1, 3)  # col span=1, row span=3
        # =================================================
        # OK, Cancel
        # =================================================
        # row += 1
        self.hbox7.addItem(spacerItem1)
        self.but_ok = QPushButton("OK")
        self.but_ok.setFont(font_bld)
        self.hbox7.addWidget(self.but_ok)
        self.but_ok.clicked.connect(self.OnOk)
        self.hbox7.addItem(spacerItem1)
        self.but_cancel = QPushButton("Cancel")
        self.but_cancel.setFont(font_bld)
        self.hbox7.addWidget(self.but_cancel)
        self.but_cancel.clicked.connect(self.OnCancel)
        self.hbox7.addItem(spacerItem1)

        self.main_vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.main_vbox.addLayout(self.hbox1)
        self.main_vbox.addLayout(self.hbox2)
        self.main_vbox.addLayout(self.hbox3)
        self.main_vbox.addLayout(self.gbox1)
        self.main_vbox.addLayout(self.gbox2)
        # self.main_vbox.addLayout(self.sheild_group_box)
        self.main_vbox.addLayout(self.hbox4)
        self.main_vbox.addLayout(self.hbox5)
        self.main_vbox.addLayout(self.hbox6)
        self.main_vbox.addLayout(self.hbox7)
        self.setLayout(self.main_vbox)

        # =================================================
        #
        # =================================================
        self.setLayout(self.main_vbox)
        self.setGeometry(300, 200, 500, 450)

        self.element_selection_comboBox.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.element_cng)
        self.oil_radio.clicked.connect(self.oil_trf)
        self.dry_radio.clicked.connect(self.dry_trf)
        self.power_input.editingFinished.connect(self.power_change)
        self.voltage_input.editingFinished.connect(self.voltage_change)
        self.typ_max_input.editingFinished.connect(self.typ_max_change)
        self.imax_input.editingFinished.connect(self.imax_change)
        self.ityp_input.editingFinished.connect(self.ityp_change)

    def voltage_change(self):
        if not self.is_number(self.voltage_input.text()):
            QMessageBox.information(self, "Error", "The Voltage value is not a number!")
            self.voltage_input.setText("220")
            return
        if float(self.voltage_input.text()) <= 0:
            QMessageBox.information(self, "Error", "The Voltage value must be > 0 !")
            self.voltage_input.setText("220")
            return

    def imax_change(self):
        if not self.is_number(self.imax_input.text()):
            QMessageBox.information(self, "Error", "The Imax value is not a number!")
            self.imax_input.setText("100")
            return
        imax = float(self.imax_input.text())
        if imax <= 0:
            QMessageBox.information(self, "Error", "The Imax value must be > 0 !")
            self.imax_input.setText("100")
            return
        typ_ratio = float(self.typ_max_input.text())
        self.ityp_input.setText(str(round(imax * typ_ratio)))


    def ityp_change(self):
        if not self.is_number(self.ityp_input.text()):
            QMessageBox.information(self, "Error", "The Ityp value is not a number!")
            self.ityp_input.setText("60")
            return
        if float(self.ityp_input.text()) <= 0 or float(self.ityp_input.text()) > float(self.imax_input.text()):
            QMessageBox.information(self, "Error", "The Ityp value must be < Imax !")
            self.ityp_input.setText("60")
            return

    def typ_max_change(self):
        if not self.is_number(self.typ_max_input.text()):
            QMessageBox.information(self, "Error", "The typ/max Ratio value is not a number!")
            self.typ_max_input.setText("0.6")
            return
        if float(self.typ_max_input.text()) > 1 or float(self.typ_max_input.text()) < 0.1:
            QMessageBox.information(self, "Error", "The typ/max Ratio value must be 0.1 < X < 1 !")
            self.typ_max_input.setText("0.6")
            return

    def power_change(self):
        """ calculate the Imax """
        if not self.is_number(self.power_input.text()):
            QMessageBox.information(self, "Error", "The Power value is not a number!")
            self.power_input.setText("1000")
            return
        if float(self.power_input.text()) <= 0:
            QMessageBox.information(self, "Error", "The Power value must be > 0 !")
            self.power_input.setText("1000")
            return
        element_type = self.element_selection_comboBox.currentIndex()
        if element_type == 4 or element_type == 5:  # Trafo only
            power = float(self.power_input.text())
            voltage = float(self.voltage_input.text())
            imax = power * 1000/(3.0 * voltage)  # kVA * 1000 /(3.0*220)
            self.imax_input.setText(str(round(imax)))
            typ_ratio = float(self.typ_max_input.text())
            ityp = imax * typ_ratio
            self.ityp_input.setText(str(round(ityp)))

    def oil_trf(self):
        self.d_input.setText("0.15")

    def dry_trf(self):
        self.d_input.setText("0.6")

    def element_cng(self):
        self.change_flag = True
        element_type = self.element_selection_comboBox.currentIndex()
        if element_type == 0:
            self.dev_img = QtGui.QPixmap("C:\mfc\modelPic\Panel.jpg")
            self.h_input.setText("1.8")
            self.d_input.setText("0.15")
            self.hc_input.setReadOnly(True)
            self.dt_input.setReadOnly(True)
            self.power_input.setReadOnly(True)
            self.voltage_input.setReadOnly(True)
        elif element_type == 1:
            self.dev_img = QtGui.QPixmap("C:\mfc\modelPic\PanelCompact.jpg")
            self.h_input.setText("1.8")
            self.d_input.setText("0.15")
            self.hc_input.setReadOnly(True)
            self.dt_input.setReadOnly(True)
            self.power_input.setReadOnly(True)
            self.voltage_input.setReadOnly(True)
        elif element_type == 2:
            self.dev_img = QtGui.QPixmap("C:\mfc\modelPic\Cable4Wcompact.jpg")
            self.h_input.setText("0")
            self.d_input.setText("0.03")
            self.power_input.setReadOnly(True)
            self.voltage_input.setReadOnly(True)
        elif element_type == 3:
            self.dev_img = QtGui.QPixmap("C:\mfc\modelPic\Cable4Wflat.jpg")
            self.h_input.setText("0")
            self.d_input.setText("0.03")
            self.power_input.setReadOnly(True)
            self.voltage_input.setReadOnly(True)
        elif element_type == 4:
            self.dev_img = QtGui.QPixmap("C:\mfc\modelPic\TrafoLong.jpg")
            self.power_input.setReadOnly(False)
            self.voltage_input.setReadOnly(False)
            self.hc_input.setReadOnly(False)
            self.dt_input.setReadOnly(False)
            self.h_input.setText("1.8")
            self.hc_input.setText("1")
            self.dt_input.setText("0.0")
            self.length.setText("1.0")
            if self.dry_radio.isChecked():
                self.d_input.setText("0.6")
            else:
                self.d_input.setText("0.15")
        elif element_type == 5:
            self.dev_img = QtGui.QPixmap("C:\mfc\modelPic\TrafoBroad.jpg")
            self.power_input.setReadOnly(False)
            self.voltage_input.setReadOnly(False)
            self.hc_input.setReadOnly(False)
            self.dt_input.setReadOnly(False)
            self.h_input.setText("1.8")
            self.hc_input.setText("1")
            self.dt_input.setText("0.0")
            self.length.setText("1.0")
            if self.dry_radio.isChecked():
                self.d_input.setText("0.6")
            else:
                self.d_input.setText("0.15")
        elif element_type == 6:
            self.power_input.setReadOnly(True)
            self.voltage_input.setReadOnly(True)
            self.dev_img = QtGui.QPixmap("C:\mfc\modelPic\Cable2W.jpg")
            self.d_input.setText("0.03")
        elif element_type == 7:
            self.power_input.setReadOnly(True)
            self.voltage_input.setReadOnly(True)
            self.dev_img = QtGui.QPixmap("C:\mfc\modelPic\Wire.jpg")
        elif element_type == 8:
            self.power_input.setReadOnly(True)
            self.voltage_input.setReadOnly(True)
            self.dev_img = QtGui.QPixmap("C:\mfc\modelPic\Cable2W.jpg")
        elif element_type == 9:
            self.power_input.setReadOnly(True)
            self.voltage_input.setReadOnly(True)
            self.dev_img = QtGui.QPixmap("C:\mfc\modelPic\Cable2W.jpg")

        self.img.setPixmap(self.dev_img)

    def OnSingleClick(self, item):
        self.result = item.text()

    def OnDoubleClick(self, item):
        self.result = item.text()
        self.close()
        return self.result

    def OnOk(self):
        if self.result == "":
            QMessageBox.information(self, "Error", "One item must be selected")
            return 
        self.close()
        return self.floor_data
        # return self.result

    def OnCancel(self):
        self.close()

    def GetValue(self):
        # return self.result
        return self.floor_data

    def do_nothing(self):
        print("nothing")

    def is_number(self, s):
        try:
            float(s)
            return True
        except ValueError:
            return False
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [grouping radio buttons in PyQt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14798058/grouping-radio-buttons-in-pyqt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution as you indicated is to use QButtonGroup, the problem is that your QButtonGroups is a local variable that will be eliminated when you finish executing the function, the solution is to pass a parent to the QButtonGroups so it will extend its scope.

```
...
direction_group = QtWidgets.QButtonGroup(self) # <--- pass the self as a parent 
...
i_group = QtWidgets.QButtonGroup(self) # <--- pass the self as a parent 
...
trafo_group = QtWidgets.QButtonGroup(self) # <--- pass the self as a parent 
...
```